# Can I sign in to console versions of Fortnite with my Mobile or PC accounts?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I play Fortnite on mobile and PC, but I am going to the game cave soon (a place with Xboxes and PS4s). On mobile I sign in with Google, and on my computer I sign in with my Epic Games account.

My question is: Can I play on the consoles at the game cave with my account? Or Will I have to create a new account to sign in with Xbox/PlayStation? And can I go back to playing on mobile/pc?

If I can play on console, can I go back to pc/mobile afterward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your Epic Games Account to sign in for console. I have a Epic Games acount that I play both on console and PC. So you will be able to use both.

I have done this before on console and I used my Epic Games Account from PC.

**Edit:** You cant play on both PC and console AT THE SAME TIME. You will be logged out of one. But you can play separatly and go back to playing on PC when your done on console (Example, I play now on PC and on Vacation on Console)

Remiender If you sign in on someone elses console, sign out after use or they might be able to use your account.

Comment: Did Sony end up resolving the Fortnite PSN bug, where it locks your Epic Games account to the PSN, even after unlinking the PSN later?

Comment: @Robotnik That's intentional, not a bug.  Once you log on to Fortnite on a console, you will lock that account out on at least one console.  Specifically, Xbox One/Switch first and you'll lock the account out on the PS4.  PS4 first and you'll lock that account out on the Xbox One and Switch.

Comment: @Powerlord I'm only quoting what I read in the news, it sounds like you have more experience with the situation than me, and if that's the case it's probably critically important to the question OP to know this, lest they stuff up their account in some way. Would you mind expanding that comment into a full answer?